# ¿Como mantener muchos productos en git?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

estoy buscando una forma eficiente de manejar varios repos de git.

Por un lado tengo tres "productos" distintos, donde cada uno tiene multiples caracteristicas, y por el otro varios clientes distintos donde ninguno utiliza el 100% de las caracteristicas o incluso requiere variaciones dentro de una.

Por ejemplo mis productos son:

- Servidor `A` en python con funcionalidades `A1`, `A2`, `A3`, `A4`...
- Portal web `B` en Angular que potencialmente consume las caracteristicas `A1` y `A2` del servidor `A`
- Aplicacion mobile `C` en React que consume `A1` y `A3` del servidor `A`

Y tengo los clientes donde

- `Z1` requiere solo la funcionalidad `A1` de las 3
- `Z2` requiere todas las funcionalidades con un agregado en `A3`
- `Zn` requiere x funcionalidades

En este momento tengo tres repositorios `ServerA`, `PortalB`, `AplicacionC`, en los cuales cada uno de los clientes tiene su propio branch, pero esta solucion es muy ineficiente al corregir cambios en una funcionalidad, ya que hay que repetir los cambios en cada branch que este afecte.
A su vez el branch "master" no significa nada, ya que no existe el producto generico como tal.

Otro problema que se genera es que para lanzar un release es necesario tener mucho cuidado con que versiones se manejan de cada repo.

Por otro lado tener un repo por cliente complicaria aun mas las cosas ya que para cambiar una funcionalidad deberia cambiar en todos los repos.